# APPS SCRIPT DATE FORMAT ISSUE

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email

I'm trying to send a table from google sheets to gmail using apps script, i have multiple dates and i want to send in this format "dd-mm-yy", but the problem is that i need to use utilites.formatdate which coverts the cell into string, so when i try to send the email it diplays that the parameters dont match the method, i think this is because in some cells date could be not fullfilled, so theres nothing written in the cell, because of this error i cant send the email, if i write dates in the cells it works but there are cases when they are not fullfilled as i said, **how can i solved this problem and send the email no matter if all the dates are filled or not?**

```
var fecha = registro.getRange("c16").getValue();
var fechaF = Utilities.formatDate(fecha, "GMT","dd-MM-YY");
```

This is the way i tried to change the format, and if there is someting written works but

```
var fecha2 = registro.getRange("e16").getValue();
var fecha2F = Utilities.formatDate(fecha2, "GMT","dd-MM-YY");
```

In the second there is nothing so it displays the error

Hope you can help me guys

I'm learning so all kind of advices you give to me are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fecha = new Date(registro.getRange("c16").getValue());
var fechaF = Utilities.formatDate(fecha, "GMT","dd-MM-YY");
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but now, when sending an email it shows random dates, is there a way to hide this dates in the email? Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to initiate Date by adding  `new DATE()` to use the converted string as DATE type and after that you can format it as you want
so your code will be

```
var fecha = new DATE(registro.getRange("c16").getValue());
```

EDIT

```
 var fechaF = Utilities.formatDate(fecha, "GMT","dd-mm-yyyy").setNumberFormat('dd-mm-yyy');
```

Comment: As i said it works perfectly but now it shows me random dates, is there a way to hide this dates or someway to show anything if there is nothing written?

Comment: var fechaF = Utilities.formatDate(fecha, "GMT","dd-mm-yyyy").setNumberFormat('dd-mm-yyy');

Comment: In that way the code doesnt work, "Utilities.formatDate(...).setNumberFormat is not a function"